# SQL - Differences between two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been looking for a while, but I do not find an answer : What are the difference between those queries ?

```
SELECT P1.att 
FROM table AS P1, table AS P2 
WHERE P2.att1=x AND P1.att2 > any P2.att2;

SELECT att 
FROM table 
WHERE att2 > any (SELECT att2 FROM table WHERE att1=x);
```

Thank's you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference is that the first query will return a row for each pair of rows in the table where `P1.att2 > P2.att2 and P2.att1 = x`, while the second query will just return one row for each row in the table where `att2` is greater than in some row where `att1 = x`. For example, if the table contains:

```
att att1 att2
1   x    10
2   y    20
3   x    15
4   z    16
5   a     5
6   b    11
```

The first query will return

```
att
2
2
3
4
4
6
```

`2` and `4` are returned twice because their `att2` are greater than `att2` in rows 1 and 3, but `3` and `5` are only greater than row 1. The second auery will just return:

```
att
2
3
4
6
```

If `att` is unique in each row, changing the first query to `SELECT DISTINCT P1.att` will get you the same result as in the first query. Or if there's a primary key, you can use `GROUP BY primary_key_column`.